# What's wrong for the error of Time Limit Exceeded on leetcode 53. Maximum Subarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is below for [leetcode 53.Maximum Subarray](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/), but [one test cas](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/294057224/testcase/)e is not passed.

How can I fix my current code to prevent Time Limit Exceeded?

```py
class Solution(object):
    def maxSubArray(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = nums[0]
        array_len = len(nums)
        for i in range(array_len):
            #print("first index" + str(i))
            total = 0
            for j in range(i, array_len):

                total = total + nums[j]
                #print(total)

                if result < total:
                    result = total

        return result
```

Comment: Your solution is `O(n^2)` and the length of list in that test case is `10^4`

Comment: just use kadane`s algorithm, google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use some algorihm function to reduce your time complexity;lick max() in c++.
You can use iteration to solut it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting TLE because your solution's runtime is O(n^2). The time complexity can be reduced by two ways. Either you need to use divide and conquer approach which has O(nlogn) runtime or [Kadane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm)`s algorithm which has O(n) runtime. Either of the approaches will be enough.